# Make an numpy array of zeros, where each row has 8 zeros, and the index which corresponds to the output changes to 1

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a numpy array of zeros:

```
Y_numpy = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
...]
```

I have:

```
Y = [1,2,7,8,3,4,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,4,6,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,...]
```

My aim is to change the value at the index to '1' in Y_numpy which is same as the value of each Y.

E.g.:

```
Y[0] = 1 => Y_numpy[0] = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y[1] = 2 => Y_numpy[1] = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
Y[2] = 7 => Y_numpy[2] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
Y[3] = 8 => Y_numpy[3] = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
Y[4] = 3 => Y_numpy[4] = [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
Y[5] = 4 => Y_numpy[5] = [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]
...
```

Let me know if you need any other information or more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Y = [1,2,7,8,3,4,6,7,8,8,8,8,8]
Y_numpy = np.array(Y)[:,None] == np.arange(1,9)
```

Output:

```
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [179]: Y = [1,2,7,8,3,4,6,7,8,8,8,8,8,4,4,4,6,3,2,3,4,5,6,7]                 
In [180]: len(Y)                                                                
Out[180]: 24
In [181]: Ynum = np.zeros((24,8),int)
```

2d array assignment; one value per row:

```
In [184]: Ynum[np.arange(24),np.array(Y)-1] = 1                                 
In [185]: Ynum[:6,:]                                                            
Out[185]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```